# String equality check by only reference

Tags: java, string

As we know if we do a check like below the output will be `equal`.

```
String s1 = "stackoverflow";
String s2 = "stackoverflow";
if(s1==s2){
    System.out.println("equal");
}
```

So my question is if i am not using `new` operator in my application to create `String` and all are strings are literals so can i use only reference equality as given above? Thanks in advance.

**N.B:** i am writing a crawler so i need to check whether i have already visited the given url that i am currently holding. I am using [`murmur hash`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) which gives me a `long` for every url but there are collision  so i need to check for the content if the url string if there is a hash collision. Hence for performance i am thinking of just comparing the reference equality of two string urls. And i am using `jsoup` for html parsing.

Comment: If you're writing a recursive crawler, not all of your strings are literals.  However, look at interning.

Comment: If every string is a literal and you don't do any operations (substring, concatenation with unknown variables, etc) on it, then you should be able to just use `==`, yes.

Comment: Please refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 7):

> if i am not using `new` operator in my application to create `String` and all are strings are literals so can i use only reference equality as given above?

If you are 100% sure that all the strings you are dealing with are plain string literals or compile-time constant expressions then yes.  The [Java Language Specification §15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) mandates that

> Compile-time constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

But if you get strings from anywhere else (e.g. reading them from a web page retrieved by your crawler, or building them using concatenation expressions that are not compile-time constants) then you must use `.equals` to compare them by value rather than by reference or `.intern()` them explicitly.

It's not always obvious whether an expression is a compile-time constant or not:

```
String s1 = "Stack";
String s2 = s1 + "Overflow"; // not a CTC
```

but

```
final String s1 = "Stack";
String s2 = s1 + "Overflow"; // _is_ a CTC, because s1 is a "constant variable"
                             // (final, with an initializer that is itself a CTC)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The VM does not guarantee described behavior, it is an optimization. To guarantee this behavior, you need to call String#intern().

This and only this will guarantee reference equality.

But do a performance test, String#equals() is probably faster :-)

Comment: Can you provide a source that elaborates on why compile-time known strings aren't guaranteed to be interned?

Comment: I probably did not read the question properly. My bad. The other answers are more precise.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is if i am not using new operator in my application to create String and all are strings are literals so can i use only reference equality as given above?

Yes , for sure. Since they are resolved at compile time , so no issues.

But keep in mind the below  scenario

```
       String s3= s2;
       String s4= s1+"";   //resolved at run time 
      System.out.println(s3==s4);  //false
      System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));//true
```

So until unless you are sure that the strings not going to be change later, you can safely use ==.

Comment: `s1+""` this is also string literal. please check your answer.

Comment: @Trying that expression is only a compile-time constant (and thus guaranteed to be interned) if `s1` is `final`

Comment: @Trying Yes. True. But s4 released the value  at run-time.

Comment: @IanRoberts thats what i am saying but the OP has mentioned it in wrong way.

Comment: @IanRoberts so s3==s4 return true not false but op has mentioned false.

Comment: @Trying  Are you sure ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ check it.

Comment: `String s1 = "stackoverflow";
        String s2 = "stackoverflow"+"";
        if(s1==s2){
            System.out.println("equal");
        } `it prints equal.

Comment: @Trying  May I have a demo, that how it's true ???  Here I can prove that It is false. https://ideone.com/9MQTjy

Comment: @Trying - Dont check s1 against s2... create s3 and s4 like suresh has done and try.. it returns false

Comment: @Trying your example is a different case entirely - the concatenation of two string literals is a compile-time constant expression but the concatenation of one literal and one (non-constant) variable is not.